# Notepad++: Replace last appearance of semicolon in every line?

Tags: notepad++, regex

My lines look like this:

```
a;b;c;d
e;f;g;h
i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p
```

What i want is this:

```
a;b;c;-d
e;f;g;-h
i;j;k;l;m;n;o;-p
```

I want to add a minus after the last appearance of a semicolon. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+;\K.+$`
- Replace with: `-$0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
  .+    : 1 or more any character but newline, greedy
  ;     : a semicolon
  \K    : forget all we have seen until this position
  .+    : 1 or more any character but newline
$       : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
-       : a dash
$0      : the whole match
```

**Result for given example:**

```
a;b;c;-d
e;f;g;-h
i;j;k;l;m;n;o;-p
```

Comment: As an alternate solution, a macro can be recorded for first line and then can be executed till end of file.

Comment: @Sandeep: May be, but I'm not sure it is simpler. How do you select the last semicolon in the macro?

Comment: @Toto: This is actually very simple but it cannot be saved for future sessions. I follow these steps. From start of first line, search for `;` and then press `HOME`. Now start recording `macro`. Press `END`, `SHIFT + F3` (to search last `;`). Press `Right arrow` and type `-`. Press `DOWN` and `HOME`. Now, stop recording and run macro till end of file. It looks dirty but hardly takes few seconds.